# Adding user with custom home directory, and setup mysql user/password

Tags: mysql, users, ftp

I want to have a way of easily adding users with a custom home directory. Also setting up an FTP & MySQL Username/Password. How might be an good way of doing that?

I am thinking something like a script run like: `setupuser [username]` then password will be generated and used for Ubuntu/FTP/MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jiewmeng, thats generally how such things are done. You should note:

1. FTP is insecure, so the password used for that should *not* be
   allowed to use SSH. I would suggest using SSH keys only for shell access, and putting people in full chroot jail.
2. MySQL is *NOT* safe to expose on the internet. Connections take up a lot of RAM, and it is very easily DoS'd off the net. Also for multi-tenant mysql, its nearly impossible to limit one user's ability to completely use up all of the resources of the box.
3. proftpd actually lets you store users/passwords in mysql.. so you can maybe leverage that to have only one place to manage the password.